# MVC Publishing issue: need to controller modifcation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish-subscribe

I am having one MVC application and published to live.it is working perfectly. today I did some small modification in controller and published the project. now I am having confusion which file to promote to Live in order to bring the controller modification. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Copy Project Dll File in bin Folder and Replace it With published one

Comment: If I copy project dll, all other modification will go to Live. For me only particular controller modification want to promote to live...Is there any way...Or we cant do like that. I am new to MVC, that why I am asking

Comment: you cant do that

Comment: Thanks for the help